Search within a range of numbers in a cell in Excel?
I have 2 columns on my worksheet, one of names and is supposed to be ranges of numbers like this

I want to search a specific number in the search cell and get the assigned name to that number in the result cell
I tried different formulas, but unable to put all together to get the desired result

What are the formulas you used?

Try using the following formula:


=XLOOKUP(F3,--TEXTBEFORE(B2:B5,"-"),A2:A5,"",-1)


Or, Using LOOKUP()
=LOOKUP(F3,--TEXTBEFORE(B2:B5,"-"),A2:A5)


Or,
=VLOOKUP(F3,IF({1,0},--TEXTBEFORE(B2:B5,"-"),A2:A5),2,1)


If it is always three digit numbers then:
=XLOOKUP(F3,--MID(B2:B5,1,3),A2:A5,"",-1)



Thanks. I go with first formula.
Can you please check my Edit

@Alex there is no edit!

in the original question

@Alex don't you think that is a different question after all?

@Alex which one is your input and which is your output here. I meant to say, like in your earlier edit it was 415 so what are you entering now?

formula will take input from the search cell (F3). And look in the ranges to check and derive assigned name

I have posted a new question

Hi @Alex when you have time, do try my formula, i have posted in your new question. !
